# Firefox not displaying styles for checkboxes

Tags: css, firefox

This is what the checkboxes look like on Chrome/Opera:

[image]

But on Firefox no styles seem to be applied:

[image]

Is any way to styling a checkbox and selected field using CSS and Bootstrap4, to get the same effect on Chrome/Opera on Firefox?

Mozilla MDN shows the [`::selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) pseudoclass, but it still won't work.

```css
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox:before {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.checkbox:checked:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  height: .5rem;
  border-color: #ff243d;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
}
.checkbox:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.125rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 1.1rem;
  height: 1.1rem;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" unchecked>Checkbox_1
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/bigeyedes/pen/BwoaRL)

Comment: Thanks, I just delete those lines, but it's not a solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is causing a problem for you, but all of the CSS checkbox styles I've seen use `opacity: 0;` on the actual checkbox, and apply the styles on the `::before` and `::after` of the `<label>` next to it;

I followed this guide: https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/pure-css-accessible-checkboxes-and-radios-buttons-54063e759bb3

And mixed it with the effect you want and this is the result:

```css
.checkbox { display: inline-block; line-height: 1rem; }
#checkbox_1 { visibility: hidden; position: relative; }
#checkbox_1 + label { cursor: pointer; }
#checkbox_1 + label::before {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#checkbox_1:checked + label::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  height: .5rem;
  border-color: #ff243d;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
}
#checkbox_1 + label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" unchecked>
  <label for="checkbox_1">Checkbox_1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks form help! It's working for me :) I'm still looking for solution about selected.